# Which http status code should be returned when the identifier in the payload does not exist?

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I've the endpoint POST /permission-period which should create a permission period for a specific user.

The payload:

```
{
    "userId": 10,
    "permissionPeriodDateFrom": "2017-12-01",
    "permissionPeriodDateTo": "2017-12-10"
}
```

If any property from the payload is invalid, i usually return 422 Unprocessable Entity, which means the syntax of the request payload is valid but it cannot be processed due to invalid data.

What status should I return if the user does not exist and I do not want to provide the client with this security related information? Should i expose the message that the user does not exist or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think HTTP status code wise I would choose a `400 - Bad request`. Regarding the returned error message I would give the user a helpful information while keeping security-related information secret.

You could return something like `The given userId is either malformed, does not exist or cannot be linked to the posted resource`. This would allow the user to identify the spot where in the body the error comes up (property `userId`) but does not tell him the exact error to prevent user enumeration.

The good news is that you obviously have a protected endpoint when creating a `permission-period` so the API user is identifiable and you can take other actions for preventing user enumeration and related brute force attacks such as consumer-based throttling or locking the API consumer after x attempts.

I hope my notes help you with your API design.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And if I have an endpoint /user/{id} where the ressource can be accessed through a slug? Should i return then 404?

Comment: Yes, when you call the resource directly and it is not found/does not exist, you should return 404. When only a reference within the body or any other parameters do not exist (as in your question) I would prefer 400 as the called resource POST /someurl actually exists, so 404 would not be correct in this case